# How to create a separate log file to print the admin details who deletes a customer profile?

Tags: magento2, custom, psr-logger

I want to create a new log file which will print the admin details who deletes a customer profile from admin panel in magento 2. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **di.xml**

> 1. app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/**di.xml**

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customLogger</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

> 2. Create a Logger folder in your module and **Logger.php** file

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Logger/Logger.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{
}
```

> 3. Create a **Handler.php** File in Logger Folder

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Logger/Handler.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Logger;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base;

class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
{
    /**
     *Logging level
     *@var int
     */
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;

    /**
     *File Name
     *@var string
     */
    protected $fileName = '/var/log/custom.log';
}
```

> Use this in your Module instead of this `use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;` add your custom logger `use Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger;`

```
use Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger;

class Test
{
  public function __construct(
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

**You can use it as**

> $this->logger->info('this is custom logger);

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this code how can I implement the plugin code. so that it prints the details and what should be included in the logger class

Comment: I have updated an answer please check.

Comment: sorry but I didnt get the changes. this code wont print the admin details and how to connect the plugin with this

Comment: In your plugin instead of this `use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;` add your custom logger `use Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger;`

Comment: You can mark it as accepted answer if it's solved your issue so it could help others.

Comment: But I have one doubt why does this classes do not have any function?

Comment: we're extending default Magento class, we can also make our functions in `Logger` and `Handler` file

Comment: OK thank you so much